# Kivy drop down bug

Tags: python, frameworks, kivy

When this drop down menu is made ​​in [Kivy](http://kivy.org/), if the the window size increases, then decreases again, the menu stops working. 
Is this some kind of bug?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner, SpinnerOption
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

Builder.load_string('''
<Janela1>:
    size_hint: .4, .4
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: 'HAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa'
    Button:
        text: 'Click me to dismiss'
        on_press: root.dismiss()
''')


class Tela(GridLayout):
    pass

class Janela1(Popup):
    pass

class programa(App):
    def build(self):
        dropdown=DropDown()
        raiz = Tela(cols=4, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=40) #declarando  o fundo

        btn = Button(text='Valor 1', size_hint_y=None, height=44)
        btn.bind(on_release=self.show_popup)
        btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
        dropdown.add_widget(btn)


        i = 0
        for lista in range(4):  
            lista=['Intervalos','Ritmo','Identificacao dos Modos','Acordes']
            mainbutton = Button(text='%s' % lista[i], size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            i += 1

            mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open)

            mainbutton.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
            raiz.add_widget(mainbutton)


        return raiz

    def show_popup(self, raiz):
        p = Janela1()
        p.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    programa().run()
```

Comment: I ran this code and it did not break for me. What OS are you using? I tested on Ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 0):

I was using python and kivy in windows and ran into all sorts of problems. I did use a virtual machine with the kivy VM and that solved a ton of issues. So if you are going to stick on windows for developing I would use this: http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html